# How to undo "Import LinkedIn" update in Careers 2?

Tags: support, jobs, linked-accounts, linkedin

I have imported my Linked In profile two times to my Careers 2 [profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/towhidulbashar). As a result it's showing *Currently Software Engineer at Insight IT Ltd.* two times in my Careers 2 profile. How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an extra experience section for Insight from the second import. To delete an experience or education section from your profile click the edit link at the bottom left of the section, then click the red remove link on the bottom right hand side of the section.